# How to write query if I have to get output using two values from the same columns

Tags: android, mysql

I want to get values from table Noon for the columns category=LD for age=1.5 and 4. I have written the following query but there is something wrong.What should i add between age = '1.5' '4'(AND,+ or something else) or some whole new query??

```
String query = "SELECT  * FROM Noon WHERE category = 'LD' AND age = '1.5' '4' " ;
```

Comment: [Between](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) Excerpt: `SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;`

Comment: @Skynet That doesn't answer the question, they are looking for cases where age is 1.5 OR 4. Not between 1.5 and 4

Comment: Oh, regretful - I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query should be like:

```
String query = "SELECT  * FROM Noon WHERE category = 'LD' AND age BETWEEN '1.5' AND '4'";
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be like this:

> String query = "SELECT  * FROM Noon WHERE category = 'LD' AND age in 
>   ('1.5','4' )"

;

Or try this:

> String query = "SELECT  * FROM Noon WHERE category = 'LD' AND (age=
>   '1.5' OR age='4' )" ;

Both should work.

please try and accept the answer if successful.